# failed upgrade 11.04 to 12.04

Tags: partial-upgrade

I did an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 but it didn't go as expected and Ubuntu asked me to do a partial upgrade.

As far as I know,everything went perfect and now I have 12.04. But whenever I check for updates or run the `sudo apt-get update` command, Ubuntu keeps installing the same number of similar packages over and over again.

According to my concern, I think even though it says the updates are fully installed they didn't get installed properly. And when I restart the PC once again, I have to install those updates. Please help.

Terminal update [details](http://justpaste.it/16xx)

Answer (score 0):

This command really helps you try this

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If help then let me know

Comment: nop it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get update` only updates the *information* about available updates. The pasted output you show is apt-get downloading lists of packages from the available repositories, to match them against your system and check whether there is anything new that should be updated.

To actually download and install the updates, you need to run

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```